# Simple class, solely for setting "globals"

Tags: php, classes, php5, static

I'm aiming for the best and simplest way to access "global" variables set in the config file for my website. So I can use them anywhere, even inside functions

It's for file versioning, and I use htaccess to rewrite urls (trim out version part)

Right now, I'm at this:

```
// config.php:

class VERS {

  static $css = '_214';
  static $js = '_167';
  static $image = '_56';
  static $other = '_19';

}

// subpage.php:

require 'settings/config.php';
echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style'.VERS::$css.'.css" />';
```

Is this an ok solution? Are there downsides and/or better ways?

I want to avoid setting multiple DEFINE's, and I aim for a short version var call (like *VERS::$css*)

*EDIT: This is not about alternatives to the filename method itself (like filename?queries etc.)*

Comment: Why use a class, if you can simply define constants? `define('CSS', '_214');` makes `CSS` available globally...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I could. But I'm already using quite many constants (config). Just wanted to avoid setting more. Tell my why not to use a class? ;)

Comment: If you really have that many constants, chances are your entire config is hard-coded into your project. That's bad practice: use a class to parse config files (ini, xml, yml, json... whatever data format you like). That's how all of the bigger PHP projects work, if only because that means you're keeping the config all in one place, and can port your code to any environment you like... tweaking it through the config files

Comment: All my constants are in the included config file only, and the site/code/settings can be ported anywhere, with minimal changes. Not THAT many constants, but 20-30. And many of them are dynamically set, according to the server/db/user environment

Comment: The number of config params tends to grow, as does the number of environments on which code needs to run. Take a look at all of the major projects out there: they all use separate config files, for good reason.

Comment: I'm using a separate config file ;)

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about a non-php file. A file that needs to be parsed separatly, and does not require to be declared in a way that is compatible with your autoloader and such... a file that needn't be `require`'ed... if nothing else, using a yml file, it makes your code more configurable

Comment: There's absolutely **nothing** wrong with having a simple separate config.php file for a small-medium site. Requiring the file is the pretty much the same as loading and parsing the file (well the result is). "Look at the major projects!" is not always the way. Why are you so hooked on that?

Comment: It's pretty clear you think there's nothing wrong with a config class, so I'm not going to argue. The only conclusive argument I can give you is modularity and portability undeniable suffer from your approach: composer dependencies that require editing in the code itself can't be updated easily. working with git becomes a pain: you'll need to ignore changes to your HEAD to avoid committing localized configs, or edit your .gitignore file all the time, that's why I'm _hooked_ on external config files, and not hard-coding params

Comment: You seem to not understand that I DO use an external config file. And it works perfectly with git. ;) Whether or not it is ini-parsed/included/required simply does not matter

Comment: Composer dependencies + are, 9/10 times git repo's. Having to edit the config files there is a pain. The next time you run composer update, you'll have to re-edit those same files. You can't use a PHP class as config file _and_ use automated build & deployment systems without faffing around with pointless scripts. end of. What is so hard to understand about that?

Comment: If you'd like to continue this, please take it to chat.

Answer (score 2):

If these are constants, use `const`, not `static`:

```
class VERS {
    const css = '_214';
    const js = '_167';
    const image = '_56';
    const other = '_19';
}
```

and then

```
echo .....VERS::css....
```

As to whether this is a good idea in general, it would be helpful to show a bigger picture: what the rest of config looks like? how it's used? etc.

Comment: Why use `const` instead of `static`? The config file is just settings used on the website.. like these version vars, database setup etc. Nothing complex

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your goal is to change the URL for any referenced resource whenever it is updated, so that the browser will know when the previously cached version is no longer in use.  However, you mentioned that you would then need htaccess rules to strip off the cache-busting version number.

A simpler cache-busting strategy would be to append the cache-busting version number as a query string instead.  If the browser fetches the URL `style.css?version=214`, and a static file named `style.css` exists, then the webserver should map that URL to the static file.  The query string would automatically be ignored by the server.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, but want to upgrade from. The query solution is far from always reliable. **Certain browsers and proxies can ignore queries, and/or it messes with the set caching**. I appreciate your intension/effort, but this does not answer my question

Comment: Instead of a query string, appending a path info might also work. That is, fetch `style.css/214`. The web server should map it to `style.css`, while user agents and proxies would have a hard time assuming that such URLs refer to different versions of the "same" resource.

Comment: Please read my question again. This is not about queries or similar

Comment: The point of appending something to the URL is cache-busting, is it not? I'm pointing out that a smarter URL versioning scheme would relieve you of the need to write htaccess remapping rules.

Comment: I like the solid proven method of having/changing the version in the filename itself. htaccess rewrite for this is simple, fast and pretty smart (one short rule, and I already use modrewrite). No need for an alternative. But thanks